# pyqt5でチェックボックスを大きくしたい

Tags: python, python3, pyqt5

python3.5を使っています。pyqt5を用いてチェックボックスを作りたいです。その際、チェックボックスの文字が小さくて見にくかったので大きくしました。しかし、チェックボックスのチェックの大きさは下の画像のように小さいままです。
[image]

ここでチェックボックスの大きさを大きくするにはどうしたらいいですか？下にここまで書いたコードを載せておきます。

```python
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QCheckBox, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5 import *

class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):      
        font=QtGui.QFont("00コミック7",30)
        #font.setPointSize(15)

        # チャックボックス作成
        cb = QCheckBox('Show title', self)
        cb.setFont(font)
        cb.move(20, 20)

        # チェックボックスにチェックを入れる
        cb.toggle()
        # チェックの状態によってタイトルを変える
        cb.stateChanged.connect(self.changeTitle)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('QCheckBox')
        self.show()

    def changeTitle(self, state):

        # チャックが入っているとき
        if state == Qt.Checked:
            self.setWindowTitle('QCheckBox')
        # チャックが入っていないとき
        else:
            # 何も引数を指定しないとタイトルがpythonになるみたい
            self.setWindowTitle('')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

スタイルシートで、サイズと画像を指定します。checked, uncheckedの他にもchecked:hover, unchecked:hover, checked:pressed, unchecked:pressed, checked:disabled, unckecked:disabled全部指定しないと可笑しな表示になるでしょう。

```
# チャックボックス作成
cb = QCheckBox('Show title', self)
cb.setFont(font)
cb.setStyleSheet(
    """
    QCheckBox::indicator {width: 500px; height: 500px;}
    QCheckBox::indicator:checked {image: url(checked.png)}
    QCheckBox::indicator:unchecked {image: url(unchecked.png)}
    """
)
cb.move(20, 20)
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。一応大きくすることはできました。しかし、これはチェック、アンチェック状態の画像を自分で用意する必要があるということで間違いないでしょうか？

Comment: その通りです。自分で用意せずにやる方法もあるかもしれませんが、僕にはわかりません。

Comment: 意外と面倒なんですね。何はともあれ回答ありがとうございます。setStyleSheetにこんな機能があるとは知らなかったので非常に助かりました。